# Is it possible to call object from another object

Tags: python, class

I am trying to make a class for colors in pygame. 
This is what I have now.

```
class color:
    white =     (255, 255, 255)
    black =     (0, 0, 0)
    red =       (200, 0 ,0)
    green =     (0, 200, 0)
    blue =      (0, 0, 200)
    brightRed = (255, 0, 0)
    darkRed =   (127, 0, 0)

color = color()
print (color.brightRed)
```

And this as expected will print (255, 0, 0).
I wonder is it possible to make something like this:

```
color = color()
print(color.red)
print(color.red.bright)
print(color.red.dark)
```

So I can get the next prints:

```
    (200, 0 ,0)
    (255, 0, 0)
    (127, 0, 0)
```

I know that this example is pointless, but I could make something else if it is possible.

Comment: Define another class that has `bright` and `dark` properties, and assign that to `color.red`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define another class

```
class Red:
    bright = (255, 0, 0)
    dark = (127, 0, 0)
    normal = (200, 0, 0)

class color:
    white =     (255, 255, 255)
    black =     (0, 0, 0)
    red =       Red
    green =     (0, 200, 0)
    blue =      (0, 0, 200)
    brightRed = Red.bright
    darkRed =   Red.dark

color = color()
print(color.red.normal)
print(color.red.bright)
print(color.red.dark)
```

You can't have `color.red` be both a user-defined class and a tuple at the same time, so you can't use `color.red` in place of `color.red.normal`. But you could have `normalRed = Red.normal` and then use `color.normalRed`.

Comment: Thnak you so much